# AWS dynamodb running issue on localhost

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have installed AWS dynamodb on my local machine and as per direction I have also installed java jdk and after navigating to dynamodb folder I put aws given command... Mean I did everything as per direction...
But my java.exe file doesn't open on localhost:8000
When I look through then I have found that java.exe file runs on 8000 port but it show 0.0.0.0:8000 
Please help me what can I do now???

Comment: Are you talking about local dynamodb?

Comment: Yes I have mentioned